# Count object array

Tags: php, arrays, object, count

I'm facing a little problem and it's driving me nuts right now.
It's probably something easy and stupid but well.. I haven't had much coffee.

This is my array when I print it:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[SelectEmployeeResult] => stdClass Object ( 
[string] => Marijke Hakvoort ) )
```

I print the string into a select menu `<select></select>`

I do this in this way:

```
$employee = array ('pkrelation' => $_SESSION['username']);
$employeeResponse = $wcfclient->SelectEmployee($employee);
print_r($employeeResponse);
?>
<td><label>User:</label></td>
<td><select name="gebruiker">
<?php
if(count($employeeResponse) < 2){
    foreach($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult as $key => $value){
        echo "<option>".$value."</option>"; 
    }
}
```

But now the problem: When I have 2 users in my object array, like this: then it doesn't show the names in my select option tags, but just 'array'.

```
stdClass Object ( 
[SelectEmployeeResult] => stdClass Object ( 
[string] => Array ( 
[0] => Marijke Hakvoort 
[1] => User Test ) ) )
```

Now, I can show this users by using this code:

```
if(count($employeeResponse) > 0){
    foreach($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult as $key => $value){
        foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
            echo "<option>".$value1."</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

But if I delete one user, it doesn't show me anything anymore.
The count function doesn't seem to work the way I want in this case..
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change code little bit as your code is:

```
foreach($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult as $key => $value){
    echo "<option>".$value."</option>"; 
}
```

Change it to:

```
foreach($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
       foreach($value as $k1 => $v1){
        echo "<option>".$v1."</option>";                
       }
    }else{
        echo "<option>".$value."</option>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Didn't even think that way! You saved my day sir.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
if (isset($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string) && count($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string) > 0) {
if (TRUE == is_array($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string)) {
    foreach ($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string as $value) {
        echo "<option>" . $value . "</option>";
    }
} elseif (TRUE == is_string($employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string)) {
    echo "<option>" . $employeeResponse->SelectEmployeeResult->string .
     "</option>";
}  }
```

(sorry for the weird layout... formatter on stackoverflow is not nice to me :( )

Comment: Vineet1982 already gave me an excellent answer, but yours is fine too :) Thanks!

Comment: I added the correct count because you stated you also had a problem with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
empty($arrayName)
```

try to check with array empty

Comment: Why would this work? The array is never empty cause it will always have 1 or more values in it.

Comment: @Ashish, foreach will only iterate if array/object have 1 or more value.

Comment: @Marijke array may be empty run the following code `$array = array();
var_dump(empty($array));`

Comment: The array is never empty, thats not possible because my program always adds 1 admin user